# why should we add () when we create a empty array

Tags: arrays, swift

we can create an empty array like this:

```
var newArray1 = [Int]()
```

I mean: what "()" means here when we create a new array, why don't we just create a new empty array by writing this:

```
var newArray2 = [Int]
```

I know it's syntax, but can somebody explain it a little to help me understand it deeply.

Comment: Another way to create an empty array is to specify the type and then initialize it with an empty array literal:  `var newArray1: [Int] = []`.

Comment: You can also do `var newArray1 = [] as [Int]`.

Comment: @vacawama Don't. That's too terse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a new array, you would use `Array<Int>.init()`. The shorthand for calling initializers is to just drop the `.init`: `Array<Int>()`.

`[Int]` is a short hand for `Array<Int>`.

Putting the two together, we can write `Array<Int>.init()` as `[Int]()`.

Comment: How to understand the difference between "var b: [Int] = Array()" and  "var c: [Int] = [ ]", why we can change "Array()" into "[]"

Comment: Because you've specified the type with a type annotation `: [Int]`, the compiler can infer that `[]` is an empty array literal containing no `Int`s

Comment: how do you know all of this? Can you refer some documents for me?

Comment: The swift language guide covers ***all*** of this, with great clarity. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309

Comment: ... also available as an iBook free from the Apple Store.  Great if you have an iPad.

Comment: @vacawama I've been told they're different

Comment: All the more reason to know about both, then.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that `[Int]` declares a type (Array of Integer), while `[Int]()` is a call to the initializer of the same type. These are two fundamentally different operations. In e.g. Scala these could be written in the same way (as scala allows you to omit the parenthesis for methods without parameters), but in Swift this isn't allowed.

Comment: `... = [Int]` does not *declare* a type. It's not declaration, it's assignment. If anything, assigning the type would require `... = [Int].self`