# difference between () and [] in array initialization in swift

Tags: swift

As I am new to swift, I couldn't understand the difference between the below two code snippets or are they both identical

var lisA = (1,2,3)

var lisB = [1,2,3]

Comment: I would highly recommend reading the [tuples](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID329) and [arrays](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID107) section of the language guide. They are very different things.

Comment: Read this post firsy http://stackoverflow.com/a/26774368/1084174

Comment: Both the answer is good, and the last link too. It really depends on what *your* question is. But in case if it's solely about array initialization, here's another link that should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41433678/why-should-we-add-when-we-create-a-empty-array/41433734#41433734

Comment: thankyou @dfd, the question was just out of curiosity where i thought there might be something similar to a list comprehension in python

Comment: @AmeyYadav, Swift has lots of thing similar to python. Swift Tuples,arrays seems similar(as I don't know a lot about python) concept as in python tuples/lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lisA is a Tuple, lisB is an Array. These are not the same type.